# What is the best way to transparently log changes to objects when using LINQ-to-SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, change-tracking

I keep track of all **changes** that are made to objects so that the user can **view** and **rollback** to any previous version of any item in the database.

The **history** database table looks like this:

```
Item     | ItemId | Field     | WhenChanged         | OldValue | NewValue
customer | 6      | LastName  | 2009-12-31 13:00:04 | Sanders  | Sanders-Smith
customer | 5      | FirstName | 2009-12-31 12:11:14 | Jym      | Jim
```

Currently I record these changes whenever the user fills out a **form** so I have complete information of the old and new state of the object.

However, now I need to make this historical data logging available from **code**. It needs to work **transparently** when **LINQ-to-SQL** is used, i.e. the developer should not have to do any extra work, i.e. the following code should cause a write to the history table as well:

```
using (var db = Datasource.GetContext())
{
    var customers = from c in db.Customers
        where c.Status == "waiting"
        select c;
    foreach(var customer in customers)
    {
        customer.Status = "finished";
    }
}
db.SubmitChanges();
```

I can imagine I can accomplish this in **two** ways:

1. **override db.SubmitChanges()** but then the question is how do I get access to the objects which are awaiting changes.
2. attach my logging method to an **OnSubmitChanges** event but I haven't been able to find a solution to this yet

**Has anyone ever worked on this problem or know of a good approach to solve it?**

Comment: Can you hook into the INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyPropertyChanging interfaces which are auto-generated by Linq to sql-metal designer or Sql-metal and build tracking around this?

Comment: Any reason you can't use database triggers?

Answer (score 2):

I've done some [similar work](http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com/2009/05/auditing-inserts-and-updates-using-linq.html) on auditing changes -- which is the first step.  My solution works by making my designer context abstract then deriving the real context from it and overriding SubmitChanges.  It works in conjunction with a separate audit context and a helper class that can take an object and construct the audit object from it.  It relies on attributes to give the necessary information on which class is the audit class for a particular object.

You can find more information on my blog at http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com.  It's too involved to repeat here.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, you can get access to the objects awaiting changes with `db.GetChangeSet()` and to know which fields changed and what was the original value, you can use:

```
ITable table = db.GetTable(entity.GetType());
ModifiedMemberInfo[] modifiedMembers = table.GetModifiedMembers(entity);
object original = table.GetOriginalEntityState(entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since L2S generates code for you, and you wish to alter the behaviour of the generated code I see two possibilities:

1. You start using T4 templates to generate the code from the dbml file and alter the template to add your functionality. This method is described [here](http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Adding-Property-Get-logging-to-LINQ-to-SQL-with-T4)
2. You add the functionality to the generated (partial) datacontext class by writing a partial class yourself. In your partial class you can implement the create/update/delete methods (CreateCustomer, UpdateCustomer and DeleteCustomer) adding the functionality to store the change.

I hope these pointers can help you on your way.